# using webcam on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

i did download cheese using sudo apt-get install cheese command then i open cheese but my USB webcam on Ubuntu 14.04 is not detected. i have enable USB port for webcam.

Answer (score 0):

Try the luvcview package/program, it can pick up some cameras cheese doesn't.

Comment: thanks it picked up webcam. but it does record only sound when i try to capture video. is there any problem in webcam or i need to use commands.

Comment: Depends on how  comfortable you are with the command line. You can check out [the Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam). VLC and FFMPEG are popular choices, but you can record with VLC from it's GUI interface. Not too hard, if you get the hang of it ;) I personally prefer it, and I'm no terminal hero. I had the same problems as you with my internal cam in Guvcview.